# running multiple maven executions with different configuration. maven ignores configuration of a configuration unless targeted by id

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin, maven-profiles

I am trying to deploy my web-app to multiple servers running Tomcat using tomcat7-maven-plugin.

Here is part of my `pom.xml` document:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>DevDeployment</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!production</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>  
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>localhost</id>     
                            <configuration>  
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                                <url>http://127.0.01:8080/manager/text</url>  
                                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                                <username>foo</username>  
                                <password>boo</password>   
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>devserver</id>
                            <configuration>  
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                                <url>http://dev_server_ip:8080/manager/text</url>  
                                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                                <username>foo</username>  
                                <password>boo</password>   
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>  
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>ProductionDeployment</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>production</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
             <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>  
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>  
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                    <version>2.2</version>  
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>production1</id>     
                            <configuration>  
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                                <url>http://production1_ip:8080/manager/text</url>  
                                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                                <username>foo</username>  
                                <password>boo</password>   
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>production2</id>
                            <configuration>  
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                                <url>http://production2_ip:8080/manager/text</url>  
                                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                                <username>foo</username>  
                                <password>boo</password>   
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>  
                </plugin>   
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

What i am trying to achieve is to have two different maven profiles, and by running first it deploys application to 2 dev servers, and by activating other it deploys application to 2 production servers.

So when i run command:

```
mvn tomcat7:redeploy -Dproduction
```

it goes to production servers, and when i run

```
mvn tomcat7:redeploy
```

it goes to dev servers.

I have successfully made profiles, and by running those commands it chooses the right one and runs it.

The problem appears when i define multiple `<executions>` with different `<configuration>` tags, maven ignores those configuration and runs the default one.

It only works if i run `mvn tomcat7:redeploy@localhost` or `mvn tomcat7:redeploy@devserver` and target an execution directly by Id.

So obviously the goal is to have to run just 2 commands: `mvn tomcat7:redeploy -Dproduction` or `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` to deploy app to all servers either production or development.

Is it possible to achieve that with executions or there is some other way?

Comment: Have you tried attaching both executions to a phase, explicitly? e.g. adding two <phase>redeploy</phase> into each execution?

Comment: yes, and running it, it tries to deploy with default configuration, deploying to localhost, and without username and password @cleberz

Comment: try mvn tomcat7:redeploy -Pproduction